# Negative hdd usage. Available is larger than fullsize

Tags: filesystems, rhel, hard-disk

Having issues with space accounting of lvm volume. 23G is available. But the full size of the partition is 20G. (So, it shows "-4.1G used" 0_O)

```
> df -h 
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01
                       20G -4.1G   23G   -  /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02
                       63G   31G   29G  52% /porta_var
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                       20G  3.3G   16G  18% /update_root
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1      99M   13M   82M  13% /boot
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Any ideas?

P.S.

> uname -a
>       Linux hostname 2.6.18-164.0.0.0.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 00:21:28 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I guess the count is simply broken. It's only modified (increased or decreased) during normal operation but not recalculated, and can be spoiled by any miscalculating or hardware fault. Reboot into single mode, remount it in readonly mode, and run fsck on it (concrete one for the FS type) with force mode, it will recalculate all quantities.

Comment: You might want to make a backup first...

Comment: What filesystem is on `/` (ext4, btrfs, …)?

Comment: Have you tried following advice provided on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/150982/df-shows-negative-values-for-used)